# strange output from g_print

Tags: c, linux, gtk

I get the following error when I compile my code:
file.h: In function 'add_new_set':
file.h:7:53: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
   g_print (gtk_entry_get_text ((GtkEntry *)((struct data *) callback_params)->entry));

here's my code:

```
struct data
{
  GtkWidget * entry;
};
void add_new_set(GtkDialog *dialog, gint response_id, gpointer callback_params)
{
  g_print (gtk_entry_get_text ((GtkEntry *)((struct data *) callback_params)->entry));
}
static struct data callback_params;
    callback_params.entry = gtk_entry_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(content_area), callback_params.entry);
    g_signal_connect(dialog,"response",G_CALLBACK (add_new_set),&callback_params);
```

now when I press the button to run the g_print part, If I type in '%s test'
I get:
(null) test

now this seems like someething that can be maliciously used

any hints on what I'm facing here and what I should do?

thanks

Comment: When using functions, for instance from the `gtk`, it is always best to actually read (and understand) the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a format specifier:

```
g_print (gtk_entry_get_text ((GtkEntry *)((struct data *) callback_params)->entry));
```

should be:

```
g_print ("%s\n", gtk_entry_get_text ((GtkEntry *)((struct data *) callback_params)->entry));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
g_print ("%s", gtk_entry_get_text ((GtkEntry *)((struct data *) callback_params)->entry))
```

to get rid of the warning. It ensures that if `gtk_entry_get_text` returns a string with conversion specifications (e.g., `%x` or `%n`) they will not be interpreted by `g_print`.

Answer (score 1):

it seems the posted code is trying to print the text returned (actually a pointer is returned) from the call to `gtk_entry_get_text()`.

To print a text string, using the g_print() function (also using the printf() function) the first parameter to g_printf() must be a string literal that contains one or more format specifiers.   Suggest trying:

```
g_print ("%s\n", gtk_entry_get_text ((GtkEntry *)((struct data *) callback_params)->entry));
```

where the `gtk_entry_get_text()` function returns a `const gchar *`